# Where does "Windows XP Mode" store the location for the VHD and VMC files?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-virtual-pc, windows-xp-mode

On Windows 7 my Windows XP Mode if fouled up but I have alternate (backup) .vmc, vhd files.

However, I'm not sure where to copy them to or (even better) how to let Windows Virtual PC "know" which files to use for XP Mode.

Where is that setting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the XML settings* of the XP Mode VM om my machine, I can see the VHD located at:

`C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows Virtual PC\Virtual Machines\Windows XP Mode.vhd`

*(Where `xxxx` is your username)*

*This information is stored in the Configuration File at the following location:

`C:\Users\xxxx\Virtual Machines\Windows XP Mode.vmcx`

Comment: my Win XP Mode file isn't in that location. It's been deleted. I need to know where VPC stores the location so that I can change that value. I.e., where are the XML settings stored? That way I can edit that file so that  XP Mode looks where where the alternat files are.

Comment: Updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Windows 7**

> Documents\My Virtual Machines

The actual .vhd and .vmc files are in subdirectories . . .

If in doubt scan your HD for *.vhd . . . You'll find them.